# Why is it possible to do absolute import in a submodule's __init__ in python?

Tags: python-3.x, import

Following [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages) when doing `import a.b.c` in python 3, the following files are executed in this order: `a/__init__.py`, `a/b/__init__.py` and `a/b/c/__init__.py`.

I am wondering how it is possible to have `a/b/__init__.py` as follows:

```py
import a.b.c
```

i.e. an absolute import in the `__init__.py`: if I follows the reasoning, I should enter an infinite loop when importing `b`:

1. execute `a/__init__.py`
2. execute `a/b/__init__.py`

   1. execute `import a.b.c`

      1. execute `a/b/__init__.py`

and so one and so forth.

However it does work and add `c` to `b` namespace.

Side question: is it equivalent to use absolute or relative imports for `__init__.py` files?

Answer (score 0):

The crucial answer comes from [this document](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Import_Statement_Overhead):

> import statements can be executed just about anywhere. It's often
> useful to place them inside functions to restrict their visibility
> and/or reduce initial startup time. Although Python's interpreter is
> optimized to not import the same module multiple times, repeatedly
> executing an import statement can seriously affect performance in some
> circumstances.

So, it seems that Python avoids reimporting the module when seeing the same import within the same namespace again.

When names of variables, functions, classes, etc. become available in the current namespace after import of the module, there typically is no need to import again (exceptions in the document linked above).

In such a way, when Python sees an import statement that would result in reimporting the names again, Python does not do that (most of the time). In this way, circular imports are avoided in the case you described.

Comment: thanks for the link. Actually I have created a repo to play a bit around with imports: https://github.com/ClementWalter/namespaces and it seems that `sys.modules` is updated even if the `__init__.py` is not completely run, or in other words that it is updated just before actually executing the `__init__.py` script. I'd like to found out more about this `sys.modules` update rule